# Some kind of Auto-downloader from an FTP Site?

Tags: linux, ftp, scripting

Some company use FTP to publish the updates that we need from then, is there a software to automatize that? or i will to bash-script the process? any ideas?

Comment: Did you try googling this before asking all of us to help you?  How about using that chance to shame the company that forces you to still use an insecure protocol?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cron Job for FTP download](http://serverfault.com/questions/157515/cron-job-for-ftp-download)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are lots of good suggestions.  Also check out [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/).

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to automatically download whatever is published to an FTP site, you could use rsync, running it as a cron job:

```
rsync -P -v -r ftp.nluug.nl::Mandrakelinux/official/2006.0/i586/install/images/ .
```

See http://www.brunolinux.com/10-General_Info/Rsync.html for more information about rsync.

Comment: Doesn't the site need to be running a rsync server?  Many public ftp servers also offer http/rsync, but I am not sure that 'some company' will.

Comment: The remote site is running on Win2k3+FTP via IIS and we have an username and password, does this matter?

Comment: Yes, it does.  IIS will not support rsync out of the box.  Rsync is a good solution for speeding up data syncronization, but it requires a client/server setup to work.

Comment: If this isn't Linux as originally tagged, then rsync is not a good choice. One of the wget/curl/ncftpget answers makes more sense then.

Answer (score 1):

Quickly

```
open ftp.address.co.uk
quote USER username
quote PASS password
cd ftp/dir
put file
bye
```

you can then run ftp -n < backup.sh, where backup.sh is the code above. I wrote some fancy create folders with todays date before running the ftp command. If anyones interested I can post them up here.

Answer (score 1):

Agree that rsync is good, but an alternative is [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/).  It has automated and interactive shell-like modes, and supports options that make mirroring simple.

Answer (score 1):

ftpcopy used to be my quick choice for mirroring:

ftpcopy is a simple FTP client written to copy files or directories
 (recursively) from an FTP server.  It was written to mirror FTP sites
 which support the EPLF directory listing format, but it also supports
 the traditional listing format (/bin/ls).
 .
 ftpls is an FTP client which generates directory listings, either in
 plain text or HTML.
 .
 **The tools only support passive mode FTP**.  There is no plan to support
 active mode.
 .
 See http://www.ohse.de/uwe/ftpcopy.html for more information.
Bugs: mailto:ubuntu-users@lists.ubuntu.com
Origin: Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to bash-script it, but wrap it around ncftpget and/or ncftpput as that will let you get or put files from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [ncftpget](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/doc/ncftpget.html)

to script ftp gets.

Answer (score 0):

I use a python script for this purpose, you can easly implement ini files for the script and if you want to schedule it under windows you can build an exe with py2exe. Youcan grab a sample code [here](http://postneo.com/stories/2003/01/01/beyondTheBasicPythonFtplibExample.html).

Answer (score 0):

`wget` can download recursivly using the `-r` (recrusive) or `-m` (mirror) options. Check the man page for more information.

You *could* write a bash script, but you probably don't need to. You could just put the wget command line into a cron and it'll be executed regularly.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to create a bash script like this:

```
#! /bin/bash

ftp -n << 'EOF'
open ftp.your_ftp_host.com
quote USER your_username_here
quote PASS your_password_here
cd gets
prompt no
mget *.txt .
bye
EOF
```