# Cron Job for FTP download

Tags: cron

I am new to the shell scripts. I just want to know automated cronjob script to download all the ftp files. Now, I am downloading manually approx 600 MB. From now onwards I have the download the files on Every saturday. Please let me know the easiest sollution.

Thanks & Regards,

G.Gopi Krishna.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a wget every sunday. With the login and the FTP password on the line, the download starts automatically.
You can do a mirror to download only the differences, and do a tar or what you want after the download.

Make a small script, and ask cron to launch it every sunday.

Comment: Or Saturday, as in the OP's question.

Comment: Oops, I was tired, I have an error on the day. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You already have it: use cron.

```
0 0 * * 6 download_file.sh
```